# Compose a path from a file name. Send file through email

Tags: mailx

I want to send to my e mail account a mail with log from program execution. This file changes everyday and it's named like this

```
log-20190703.gz
```

My attempt:

```
#!/bin/bash
log_file=logs-$(date +"%Y%m%d").gz
echo "Log file for project" | mailx -s "Log file for start_ux" -a /srv/python/myfold/proj/Log_UX/${log_file}  myemail@gmail.com
```

that gives me an error:

```
log_file command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

My mailx is using option `-a` to append a header to the mail. Try option `-A` to send an attachment.

**Edit:**

The problem was solved by OP by removing a space character "between variable name and equal sign". Option `-a` was correct on CentOS and not the problem.

Comment: it says Account /srv/python/myfold/proj/Log_UX/log-20190703.gz doesn't exist

Comment: @MarcoFumagalli But the file exists and is readable (`zless /srv/python/myfold/proj/Log_UX/log-20190703.gz`)?

Comment: yes it exists. I can extract it and use cat on it

Comment: @MarcoFumagalli Hmm. Does `(uuencode /srv/python/myfold/proj/Log_UX/${log_file} ${log_file}; echo "Log file for project") | mailx -s "Log file for start_ux" myemail@gmail.com` work?

Comment: Hmm... What Unix is this and what does the manual for `mailx` on that Unix say the correct option for attachments is? "Account ... does not exist" sounds odd. On Linux it's usually `-A`, BSD does not do attachments with `mailx`, and I'm uncertain for AIX and Solaris.

Comment: @MarcoFumagalli You said `log-20190703.gz` is the name of the logfile, but you are using `logs-$(date +"%Y%m%d").gz` with an additional "s" in the script.

Comment: Are you sure you are using curly brackets and not just standard ones? So are you definitely using ${log_file} and not $(log_file)

Comment: Ok solved my issues. I'm on CentOS and i have to use -a instead of -A and also no space between variable name and equal sign